# Side by Side display of parallel arrays in java

Tags: java, parallel-arrays

I'm quite new to java and I've written the code to display the values of the following parallel arrays:

```
short[] Years = {1995, 1997, 1998,1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012};

String[] Months = {"January", "February", "June", "January", "March", "June", "July", "August", "September", "March", "May", "January", "March", "July", "November", "March", "June"};
```

Currently when I run it, they display on top each other. I'm trying to get it to display side by side. 
How can I do that?

This is the piece of code for displaying them:

```
System.out.println("Years");
for(short temp: years)
{
System.out.println(temp);
}
System.out.println("Months");
for(String temp: months)
{
System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: im trying to put it in the question

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are of equal length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Years.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Years[i] + '\t' + Months[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please notice that this will give you an `OutOfBounds exception` if the two Arrays isn't of equal length

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
int length = Years.length > Months.length ? Months.length : Years.length;
for(int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    System.out.println(Years[index] + '\t' + Months[index]);
}
```

And i suggest reading [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: it works for displaying them side by side, but for each year it posts all the months. eg 1995 January, 1995 February and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
 short[] years = {1995, 1997, 1998,1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012};
    String[] winners = {"January", "February", "June", "January", "March", "June", "July", "August", "September", "March", "May", "January", "March", "July", "November", "March", "June"};
    System.out.println("Years"+"\t"+"Premiers");
    int i = years.length-1;
    int j= winners.length-1;
    int  k=0;
int l=0;
    do{
            i--;
            j--
        System.out.println(years[k++]+"\t"+winners[l++]);
    }while(i>=0 || j>=0);
```

You will found the output like:

```
Years   Premiers
1995    January
1997    February
1998    June
1999    January
2000    March
2001    June
2002    July
2003    August
2004    September
2005    March
2006    May
2007    January
2008    March
2009    July
2010    November
2011    March
2012    June
```

Comment: you should check the condition in your while statement. right now you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks.. Edited.. Just forgot to add two lines. now fine?

Comment: interesting... i had expected `while(i>=k && j >=l)`